# Rave Reports 9.0 - выгрузка в файл (PDF и RTF)

Tags: delphi, pdf, ravereport

1. Есть рабочий отчёт (пример в скрине), но проблема вылезла в следующем - при использовании компонент `RvRenderPDF` - файл получается с иероглифами. Весь интернет, форумы говорят о невозможности подружить этот компонент с русскими буквами и, дескать, надо переходить на другой генератор. Шрифты в отчёте менял.
   Если есть опыт у кого-то исправления этого недочёта, прошу подсказать. (правки через реестр крайне не желательны, так как ПО по многим филиалам).

   2. И ещё одна непонятность - прибег к попытке использовать `RvRenderRTF` - но он выгрузил вот такую кашу:
      `{\rtf1\ansi{\fonttbl{\f0\fcharset1\fprq0 Arial;}{\f1\fcharset204\fprq0 MS Sans Serif;}}{\colortbl;\red0\green0\blue0;\red255\green255\blue255}\paperw16836\paperh11904\landscape\lytprtmet\viewkind1{`
      Эту кашу не WordPad, не MS Word не понимает.

Как быть? Как добиться нужного результата?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**UPD:** А вот, если даже просто слова в нём написать, то всё равно эффект такой же:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

### Ответ: Всё... Я сдался и перевёл весь этот отчёт программно и не программно в FastReport. (RaveRaport - это тихий ужас!)

### Его наверное все разработчики использовали лишь один, два раза в проектах... И всё. Увидев что это за громоздкий, неповоротливый монстр - бежали от него!

Comment: 1. Попробуйте входные данне сконвертировать в другую кодировку. А в целом по возможности перенести все например в `FastReport`. 2. В делфи компонент был для отображение `rtf` документов. Попробуйте просмотреть в нем.

Comment: Немного не понимаю, как конвертировать текстовые поля самого Rave-Report формы отчёта? Там шрифт Arial, Кириллическое начертание.

Comment: Я о данных, которые попадают в отчет. Попробуйте сначала с малого. Преобразовать строку в `Ascii`, `Utf8` и вывестив  отчет.

Comment: @androschuk - проблема-то не в том, что какие данные входят (в каком формате), а в том, что даже в статическом формате текст не сохраняется в нормальном виде (дополнил вопрос ещё одним скриншотом).